# Object as a key in treemap in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, treemap

CompareObj is a class in java It consists of three attributes `String rowKey, Integer hitCount, Long recency`

```
public CompareObj(String string, Integer i) {


    this.rowKey = string;
    this.hitCount = i%10;
    this.recency= (Long) i*1000;
}
```

Now I created a treeMap

```
Comparator<CompareObj> comp1 = (e1,e2) -> e1.getHitCount().compareTo(e2.getHitCount());
    Comparator<CompareObj> comp2 = (e1,e2) -> e2.getRecency().compareTo(e1.getRecency());
    Comparator<CompareObj> result = comp1.thenComparing(comp2);
    TreeMap<CompareObj, CompareObj> tM = new TreeMap<CompareObj, CompareObj>(result);

    for(int i=0;i<=1000;i++)
    {

        CompareObj cO = new CompareObj("A"+i, i);
        tM.put(cO,cO);
    }


    for(int i=0;i<=1000;i++)
    {

        CompareObj cO = new CompareObj("A"+i, i);
        CompareObj values = tM.get(cO);
        System.out.println(values.getRowKey()); // Line 28: get Null Pointer Exception
    }
```

Also I overide hashCode and Equals. Still I get nullponter exception.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return  Objects.hash(getRowKey());
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(this==obj) return true;
    if(!(obj instanceof CompareObj)) return false;
    CompareObj compareObj = (CompareObj) obj;
    return Objects.equals(this.getRowKey(), compareObj.getRowKey());
}
```

Here when I try to retrive value from treemap back I get Null Pointer exception in the line mentioned. How to solve this

If I want to implement comapareTo() of Comaprable interface, how should I implement if there is multiple sort conditions.

Comment: Your comparator can be more simply implemented as `comparing(CompareObj::getHitCount).thenComparing(reversed(comparing(CompareObj::getRecency)))`

Comment: If `recency` is declared as `Long`, `this.recency= i*1000;` shouldn't compile.  Please paste the code as you compiled and ran it.  Once the `recency` line is fixed, the code runs fine: http://ideone.com/H3ljCt

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: `comparing(CompareObj::getHitCount) .thenComparing(CompareObj::getRecency, reversed())`

Comment: @ManuJoy, casting to `Long` won't compile either.  You should either cast to `long` or use `Long.valueOf(i * 1000)`.  Again, since your question is about a runtime exception, please paste the code _exactly_ as you compiled and ran it.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to understand, is the `NullPointerException`. If you get that exception on the exact line

```
System.out.println(values.getRowKey());
```

then either `System.out` or `values` is `null`. Since we can preclude `System.out` being `null`, it’s the `values` variable, which contains the result of `get` and can be `null` if the lookup failed.

Since you are initializing the `TreeMap` with a custom `Comparator`, that `Comparator`determines equality. Your `Comparator` is based on the properties `getHitCount()` and `getRecency()` which must match, which implies that when the lookup fails, the map doesn’t contain an object having the same values as reported by these two methods.

You show that you *construct* objects with the same values but not the code of these getters. There must be an inconsistency. As [Misha pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30883232/object-as-a-key-in-treemap-in-java-8#comment49809438_30883232), your posted code can’t be the code you have ran when getting the exception, therefore we can’t help you further (unless you post the real code you ran).